# Enlarge Chart - VBA Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have written the below code to create a chart when a drop down menu option is selected. The problem is my chart is small and I want to write additional code to enlarge the chart shown to the user. How do I do this?

```
Function Categorical_Chart_Creation(Category As String, Range_A As String, Range_B As String)

'Creates column chart

Set objSelection = Worksheets("Summary Data").Range(Range_A, Range_B) 'Select area to chart

Dim objChart As Chart

Set objChart = Charts.Add

With objChart

.SetSourceData objSelection

.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

.PlotBy = xlColumns

.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale

.HasLegend = False

.HasTitle = True

.ChartTitle.Text = Category

.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True

.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Week Beginning"

.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True

.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Total Hours"

.Name = Category

.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"

End With

End Function
```

Comment: dealing with `With objChart` you could directly change it with `.Height` (the whole height of the object) or `.Width`... But a hint: function = return of value/object whatever and sub = do something for real... better change it to a sub in the first place... also, you never use your `objChart` after the `With`... so in this example you could directly go with `With Charts.Add` :P

Answer (score 0):

You can access the chartarea width and height.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim cht As ChartObject

Dim c As ChartObject
Set c = ws.ChartObjects(1)
c.Chart.ChartArea.Width = 4
c.Chart.ChartArea.Height= 4
```

Or adjust the charts ScaleHeight & ScaleWidth

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 0.6775, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 0.7638888889, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

**NOTE:**
Manipulating chart size seems to have been removed from stand alone charts in later versions of Excel (2010+). https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ded0b457-b9ba-4633-ac75-4ff36472b40c/resizing-charts-in-chart-sheet-problem-in-different-version-of-excel?forum=isvvba

If you look at the properties of a chart that is on a worksheet. You see

[image]

If you look at a stand alone chart. You don't get the size options.

[image]

Comment: I can resize charts that are on a worksheet but there seems to be an issue with resizing standalone charts in newer versions of excel. May have something to do with this.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ded0b457-b9ba-4633-ac75-4ff36472b40c/resizing-charts-in-chart-sheet-problem-in-different-version-of-excel?forum=isvvba  I would add your chart to a sheet and then you can change the size as you wish.

Comment: The code posted by the OP creates a chart sheet, then moves it to a worksheet. So he needs to resize the chart on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing up your code...

```
Function Categorical_Chart_Creation(Category As String, Range_A As String, Range_B As String)
  'Creates column chart

  Dim objSelection As Range
  Dim objChart As Chart

  Set objSelection = Worksheets("Summary Data").Range(Range_A, Range_B) 'Select area to chart

  Set objChart = Worksheets("Charts").Shapes.AddChart.Charts
  With objChart
    .SetSourceData objSelection
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .PlotBy = xlColumns
    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Category
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Week Beginning"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Total Hours"
    .Name = Category
    With .Parent ' ChartObject (container of embedded chart)
      ' size in points
      .Height = 350
      .Width = 500
    End With
  End With
End Function
```